# How to use Gallery with ice cream sandwich

Tags: android, layout, carousel, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm developing an app that is required to use **Carousel** in it, and the most famous lib I found to use carousel is [polidea](http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/source/browse/?r=426d8f7c1aef7cf4bf127cf58adb1d7a78b0a91e#hg/), this lib *extends* `android.widget.Gallery`, and i found that this class was deprecated in (**API level 16**) or what known as **JellyBean**. but unfortunately my app required to run on (**API level 14**) or what know as **IceCreamSandwich**, So, is there's is a way to add gallery to *ice cream sdk*? or is there's another lib that runs **Carousel** and works on *ice cream*?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at EcoGallery https://github.com/falnatsheh/EcoGallery.
You can make the Carousel extend EcoGallery instead of Gallery